# OCR Support with Tesseract via SOLR

Tags: solr, ocr, tesseract, apache-tika

Good day,
I'm trying to configure `SOLR` to use `Tesseract OCR` engine for text extraction from images, but did not have success yet.

SOLR extracting fine text from structured text documents (.xls, .pdf, doc, etc), but it does not want to call Tesseract module for text recognition.

I'm using

- SOLR v.7.4.0
- Tesseract version 4.1.1
- TIKA 1.18 version (build-in in SOLR, no standalone version)

Tesseract is installed in to the following directory:

```
/usr/share/tesseract/4/tessdata/
echo $TESSDATA_PREFIX - > /usr/share/tesseract/4/tessdata/
tesseract -v
tesseract 4.1.1-rc2-20-g01fb
leptonica-1.76.0
  libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 1.2.90) : libpng 1.5.13 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.7 : libwebp 0.3.0
```

Command `tesseract test.jpg  test.txt`  produces accurate txt file with *OCRed* content from test.jpg.

*solrconfig.xml*, *TesseractOCRConfig.properties*, *ParseContent.xml* files were modified to point to *Tesseract* installation.

Has anybody done such configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Good day,
We solved the situation. Here is what was used and changed:
In our installation we used Tesseract  version 3.05, Tika version 1.17, SOLR version 7.4.  We actually, had TIKA version 1.17, not 18. 
1. Changed from HOCR to TXT  >>>      in file parseContext.xml
2. Had to start SOLR as a root user.
Version 4.1.1 is not compatible with TIKA 1.17 , so we will upgrade SOLR to version 7.7, TIKA version 1.19 and will try to install Tesseract 4.1.1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHD9e.png)